# "Client authentication has not been correctly installed" error when trying to attach client auth certificate

Tags: delphi, authentication

I have a Delphi application that needs to attach a client authentication certificate to all of it's SOAP webservice calls. The code that does this attachment has worked for years with a variety of different certs, but when trying to use it with a new cert I'm getting this error :

GetWinInetError:[12046][Client authentication has not been correctly installed]

when I do :

```
result := WinInet.InternetSetOption( Data, INTERNET_OPTION_CLIENT_CERT_CONTEXT, PCC, Sizeof( CERT_CONTEXT ) )
```

The new cert on the surface looks similar to others that work. It has code signing and Client Authentication privileges enabled on it. Any ideas on what else to check with the certificate?